# how to correctly download multiple file faster and asynchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I've try to use script from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But when i try to download multiple files, the time  consumed for download a site(same site) is increased as per request, the result are:

```
retrive time: 1500 ms
retrive time: 1500 ms
retrive time: 2721 ms
retrive time: 4089 ms
retrive time: 5255 ms
retrive time: 5708 ms
retrive time: 6485 ms
retrive time: 6916 ms
retrive time: 7421 ms
retrive time: 8139 ms
```

here is my code(note: httpwebrequest keepalive is close) :

```
     static void Main()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            HttpWebRequest_BeginGetResponse req = new HttpWebRequest_BeginGetResponse();
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(req.start))
            {
                IsBackground=true

            }.Start();


        }
        Console.ReadLine();   
    }
```

and here is where i put the stopwatch

```
            IAsyncResult result =
              (IAsyncResult)myHttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RespCallback), myRequestState);
            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), myHttpWebRequest, DefaultTimeout, true);
            Stopwatch wtch = new Stopwatch();
            wtch.Start();
            allDone.WaitOne();
            wtch.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine("retrive time: "+wtch.ElapsedMilliseconds+" ms");
```

what is correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all requests are hitting the same target (same host in the URL) then you are hitting the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`, which by default is [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultpersistentconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The default number of persistent connections (**2**) allowed on a ServicePoint object connected to an HTTP/1.1 or later server.

Meaning that when you start 100 WebRequests to the same host, 2 get posted and 98 get queued up. You may want to experiment with increasing the value. Read [Understanding MaxServicePointIdleTime and DefaultConnectionLimit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit.aspx).

Your timing corroborate this: only first two requests are truly parallel. Then subsequent requests are serialized and start only as previous requests complete, resulting in the execution times you see.

As a side note, the default value (2) is the one conforming to RFC2616:

> Clients that use persistent connections SHOULD limit the number of simultaneous connections that they maintain to a given server. **A single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with any server or proxy**. A proxy SHOULD use up to 2*N connections to another server or proxy, where N is the number of simultaneously active users. These guidelines are intended to improve HTTP response times and avoid congestion.

Comment: will it limited , even if i already set httpwebrequest's keepalive to close state ?

Comment: Read the articles linked. They explain what it does and answer your question.

Comment: thx, i got very impressive result , with the code above + parallel.invoke + setting servicepoint